# How to define callbacks for Task API?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Reading the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push), it seems it is possible to use a **webhook** as a callback, once the pushed task has executed successfully.

I can't find any example how this is done though.

```
from google.appengine.api import taskqueue
taskqueue.add(url='/worker', params={'key': key})
```

This is how a task is pushed in the queue. However how does the task know it is finished and shall call its defined callback url? How do I pass in the callback Url to the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting confused.  From the docs

> App Engine executes push tasks by sending HTTP requests to your app.
>   Specifying a programmatic asynchronous callback as an HTTP request is
>   sometimes called a web hook. The web hook model enables efficient
>   parallel processing.

There is no callback at the end or completion of a running task.  The queue calls the URL (your handler), and in your example `/worker` this triggers the work to be performed which is defined in your code that is invoked when calling /worker

There is nothing magical here, the whole process is just scheduled calls to a nominated URL in your appengine app.  The only extra special bits are the tasks can run for 10mins, and if the web request doesn't finish with a 200 status it can be retried.